# Pass react component inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The server returns something like:

content = `<p> Hello world :smile: <strong> NICE </strong> !</p>` - this is because we support markdown.

Now I have a parser that parses everything with `:{text}:` into an emoji. I am using `emoji-mart` for this one.

So this is what content looks like now:

`<p> Hello world ${<Emoji emoji=":smile:" />} <strong> NICE </strong> !</p>`

Currently without the emoji parser what we do is:

```
return React.createElement('div', { 
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
    __html: content,
  }
});
```

However, since we now concatenating the `content` to contain the Emoji from `emoji-mart` how will I pass this to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` without breaking the markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon playing around with the situation I discovered that you can actually pass use functional components and return string instead: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart#using-with-dangerouslysetinnerhtml (Specific for my problem regarding `emoji-mart`)

So what I did with my other Components are the same, instead of calling a React component I created a function instead:

```
function testComponent(props) {
  const { style, className, children, html } = props;

  if (html) {
    return `<span style='${style}'  class='${className}'>${children || ''}</span>`;
  }

  return (
    <span style="${style}" class="${className}">
      ${children || ''}
    </span>
  );
}
```

And called it as:

```
function testComponent(props) {
  const { content } = props; // content is a markdown and can be a stringified image tag

  return testComponent({ children: content, html: true });
}
```

And for the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

(render function inside of your react component)

```
render() {
    const props = {
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
        __html: testComponent(this.props.content),
      },
    };

    return React.createElement('div', props);
```

}

This is hackier, but less expensive than using:

```
renderToString()
renderToStaticMarkup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `React.renderToStaticMarkup(JSXInstance)`, in your case:

```
<p> Hello world ${React.renderToStaticMarkup(<Emoji emoji=":smile:" />)} <strong> NICE </strong> !</p>
```