# How to pass react component into dangerouslySetInnerHtml?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I cannot change this statement in my sourcecode:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template }} />
```

How can I replace the template for a react component? Like:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: someReactComponent }} />
```

How can in insert a reactjs component in ?

Comment: Possible duplicte of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186102/pass-react-component-inside-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: That ain’t working

Comment: Why do you even have to do this? `<div><someReactComponent /></div>`. There's a reason why it uses the word "dangerously"...avoid using it if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [FrankerZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/frankerz),

> Why do you even have to do this? `<div><someReactComponent /></div>`. There's a reason why it uses the word "dangerously"...avoid using it if you have to.

Yes, obviously. You shouldn't be using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` most of the time as far as possible.

If you are trying to render static markup, then you may use `renderToStaticMarkup`. The linked post has also stated that but will not work because it is being used from `React` instance. You need to use it from `ReactDOMServer`:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(statticElement)
```

> This doesn’t create extra DOM attributes that React uses internally, such as data-reactroot. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes can save some bytes.

See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) for more information on it.